# pure javascript equivalent of jquery replace()

Tags: javascript

In jquery I use replace like this

`replace('old text','new text')`

How do I do the same thing with pure javascript?

Comment: String#replace *is* built in to JavaScript: `"x".replace("x", "y") == "y" # => true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *is* pure Javascript. See [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```

Comment: It's best to provide the core content of the linked page in the event the page is removed or becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

replace is a method on string objects in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

That syntax you list is pure javascript, i.e.

```
string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using

```
string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)
```

For ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Visit Microsoft!";
document.write(str.replace("Microsoft", "Stackoverflow"));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var str="fooz bard";
alert(str.replace("foo", "baz")); //bazz bard
```

> Returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

Answer (score 0):

`'string'.replace` is native javascript method. Use can just use

```
console.log( 'string'.replace('ing', 'wow') ); // 'strwow'
```

if you want to replace one dom element with another there is an ease way:

```
oldElem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, oldElem);
```